# Github OAuth API keeps returning bad verification code

Tags: javascript, axios, oauth, localhost, github-api

I am trying to mess around with APIs and so I am having an issue with my server.js file for my backend server. I keep getting the error message in my console.log saying bad verification code, The code passed is incorrect or expired, 'https://docs.github.com/apps/managing-oauth-apps/troubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors/#bad-verification-code'. I am getting the code back from GitHub but once I try to pass the authentication code to get the access_token I get this error. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this issue? I am not sure if my API is the issue or my server.js is the issue. Please help.

I created my own API on localhost:4000. I created the GitHub OAuth App and have the Client ID *and* Client Secret. When going to localhost:4000 I get the message:

> {"message":"Unauthorized"}

So when going to localhost:4000/auth/github I can access the data in my database and display it on localhost:4000 since it redirects me back once I am authenticated.

Since then I started to create a frontend app to interact with my API. I created a new GitHub OAuth App and have my new Client ID and Client Secret. My frontend app is running on localhost:4001. The frontend is app.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const accessToken = process.env.SECRET_KEY

  useEffect(() => {
    if (accessToken) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [accessToken]);

async function fetchData() {
  try {
    // Use the obtained access token to fetch data from your API
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4002/api/data', {
      headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });
    console.log("response")
    setData(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
}

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>API Data</h1>
      <a href="http://localhost:4002/auth/github">Sign in</a>
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => (
          <li key={item._id}>
            {`${item.firstname} ${item.lastname}, Age: ${item.age}, Color: ${item.color}`}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also created a server.js file for my frontend which is running on localhost:4002.

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require('cors')
const passport = require('passport')
const GitHubStrategy = require('passport-github').Strategy
const http = require('http')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()

// ... (other middleware and configurations)
console.log('Server file is being executed')

app.use(cors({ 
    origin: 'http://localhost:4001',
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
})) 

app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: false,
    limit: '10mb'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.NEW_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.NEW_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:4002/auth/github/callback",
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    return done(null, profile);
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    // Serialize user data into the session
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
    // Deserialize user data from the session
    done(null, obj);
});

app.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github'), (req, res) => {
    console.log("just normal")
    // This callback function will be executed after successful authentication
    res.sendStatus(200); // You can send any response you want here
});

app.get('/auth/github/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/auth/github' }),
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const code = req.query.code

            const querystring = require('querystring')
            
            // Inside the callback route handler
            const data = querystring.stringify({
                client_id: process.env.NEW_CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: process.env.NEW_CLIENT_SECRET,
                code: code,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            })
            console.log("word:", data)

            const authOptions = {
                url: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(process.env.NEW_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.NEW_CLIENT_SECRET).toString('base64'),
                }, 
                data: data
            }

            console.log('test', authOptions)
            console.log('gone:', authOptions.data)
            console.log('over here:', code)
            console.log('Sending HTTP request:');
            console.log('Method:', authOptions.method);
            console.log('URL:', authOptions.url);
            console.log('Headers:', authOptions.headers);
            console.log('Data:', authOptions.data);
            const response = await axios.post(authOptions.url, data, {
                headers: authOptions.headers,
                // data: authOptions.params
        });
            console.log('Received HTTP response:');
            console.log('Status:', response.status);
            console.log('Headers:', response.headers);
            console.log('Data:', response.data);
            console.log("mo:", response)
            console.log("response from Github:", response.data)
            if (response.data.access_token) {
                const accessToken = response.data.access_token
                console.log("Access Token:", accessToken)
                res.redirect('http://localhost:4001')
            } else {
                console.error("No access token received from Github.")
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error here'})
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error exchanging code for access token:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error 2' });
        }
    }
)


function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' })
}

app.get('/protected-route', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    // Route content for authenticated users
});

const server = http.createServer(app)

server.listen(4002, () => console.log('Server Started'));
```

I have tried checking to see if my Github OAuth App data is correct and it looks to be correct. I have tried changing the way the /auth/github/callback is working and nothing has worked. I think it has something to do with my axios.post but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have read through Githubs "Authorizing OAuth apps" Doc and still no luck.

Comment: Did you try to remove the strigify and leave axios to handle the content type by just passing the object?

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff I did try that a while ago and it didn't work. I also just tried it again and still, getting the same error.

Comment: What about adding the redirect_uri as per the documentation, when exchanging the code?

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff Added it this section below but still got the same error....


`const data = {
client_id: process.env.NEW_CLIENT_ID,
   client_secret: process.env.NEW_CLIENT_SECRET,
   code: code,
   redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4002/auth/github/callback',
   grant_type: 'authorization_code',
}`

Comment: Are you sure you have to exchange the code for token on your own? Doesn't passport already do that for you?

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski You're correct! I was really overthinking the entire process. I was able to get it to work by just using the following code below:

`app.get('/auth/github/callback',
    passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    (req, res) => {
        console.log('GitHub Authenitcation Successful')
        console.log('Access Token:', req.query.code)
        console.log(passport)
        res.redirect(`http://localhost:4001?accessToken=${req.query.code}`)
    }
)`

Comment: Remember that you can add it as an answer and accept it. It will help people that find your question in the future.